# Connection to 2 databases on one SQL Server instance

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public static SqlConnection OpenConnection2DB()
{
    string s = @"Data Source=********;Initial Catalog=Parking;User ID=sa;Password=*******";
    SqlConnection KetNoi = new SqlConnection(s);
    KetNoi.Open();
    return KetNoi;
}

public static void DongKetNoi(SqlConnection KetNoi)
{
    KetNoi.Close();
}

public static DataTable TruyVanLayDuLieu(string sTruyVan, SqlConnection KetNoi)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sTruyVan, KetNoi);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}

public static DataTable GetDataForm2DB()
{
    string sTruyVan;
    sTruyVan = "SELECT * FROM[parking].[dbo].[TicketMonth] AS A INNER JOIN[fishcm - cardlog].[dbo].[Cardlog] as B ON A.ID = B.ID and A.Stt = B.Stt";

    con = OpenConnection2DB();

    DataTable dt = TruyVanLayDuLieu(sTruyVan, con);

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

The query is right, I checked it with SMSS and it works. My problem is how to open connection for 2 databases on the same server, `parking` and `fishcm - cardlog`.

I was looking for around, and see more people advised open 2 connection strings. But it is good in this case, both of databases cannot collate data with each other?

Comment: If I read your question right, you are asking how to do a join on two different databases?

Comment: Also, are the two databases on the same server, and does your server user have access to both?

Comment: Oh No, I ask for ConnectionString, my query was get data from 2 Databases (it works on SQL server Management Studio) But, i need apply it into C# Winform. and I stuck at ConnectionString

Comment: Like you see, in "OpenConnection2Db", I only give ConnectionString for "Parking", so when it run, it's false.

Comment: Your connection string doesn't need to include a default database. `Data Source=****;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;` is fine as long as your fully qualifying your tables with the database name.

Comment: I was test with only 1 database, like you advise, I remove default database and it get the issue "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'fishcm - cardlog.dbo.Cardlog'.'"

Comment: my query is "select * from [fishcm - cardlog].[dbo].[Cardlog]"

Comment: @Jerry I'm sorry, may be I'm wrong, your way is work, tks

Comment: What was your issue?

Comment: the last query is wrong [fishcm - cardlog].[dbo].[Cardlog] is not have space

Comment: it should be [fishcm-cardlog].[dbo].[Cardlog]

Comment: I was test with 2 databases with your way, it works. the connection string "Data Source=****;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" can connection to all database in this server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked, you're welcome